# System.speech says "area code" on numbers

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I am using simple C# code to let a program talk

```
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true) {
            SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            speaker.Rate = 1;
            speaker.Volume = 100;
            speaker.Speak(stringout);
```

The problem is that string out contains sentences with numbers. And Microsoft Speech recognizes these as 'area codes'. So for example instead of saying

```
sample 90 123 40
```

I hear:

```
sample *area code* 90 123 40
```

How to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
speaker.SpeakSsml("sample <say-as interpret-as=\"string\" format=\”digit string\” detail=\”string\”>90 123 40<say-as>");
```

If that works, do a RegEx replace on your string in to wrap numbers in that string.

Comment: the strings are not always formated like that, they can have all kind of structures of numbers

Comment: Do you mean they're not all integers? Because it'd still be possible to create a RegEx to find them.

TBH, it's weird you're seeing this problem anyway - can you give more code?

Comment: Well another program provides the string that says lines
My program catches them over a serial connection.
There can be words in it and integers or even floats etc
It just has to speak out just the numbers as numbers not as phone numbers or areal codes. (i dont want it to be that smart), can i turn it off somhehow.

Numbers can be negative too.
But their position in the strings wont be fixed, and more numbers might exist, 

Regarding to speech i dont do anything else in my code with it.